# Why am I obtaining a nested exception when using @Autowired annotation in Spring JUnit test?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

We're starting to learn Spring on university so we have to develop a project with JPA so I had to test that JPA is working properly. The problem is that I'm obtaining this trace when executing the test.

> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'persistence.DatabaseTest': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'uS';
>   nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException:
>   No qualifying bean of type 'services.UserService' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate.

I'm not sure which element is throwing that nested exception. These are my classes:

**main.test.persistence.DatabaseTest**

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = Application.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@IntegrationTest({"server.port=0"})
    public class DatabaseTest {
    private User u1, u2, u3, u4;
    @Autowired
    private UserService uS;

    @Before
    public void setUp(){
        //Here I initialize users but nothing like uS = whatever;
    }

    @Test
    public void testUser() {
        assertTrue(uS.findAll().size()==0);
        addUsers();
        assertTrue(uS.findAll().size()==4);
        assertTrue(uS.checkExists(u1.getId()));
        assertTrue(uS.checkExists(u2.getId()));
        assertTrue(uS.checkExists(u3.getId()));
        assertTrue(uS.checkExists(u4.getId()));
        deleteUsers();
        assertTrue(uS.findAll().size()==0);
    }

    private void addUsers(){
        uS.save(u1);
        uS.save(u2);
        uS.save(u3);
        uS.save(u4);
    }
}
```

**main.java.services.UserService**

```
public interface UserService {

    void save(User user);
    void delete(User user);
    boolean checkExists(Long id);
    List<User> findAll();
}
```

**main.java.services.impl.UserServiceImpl**

```
@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService{

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository repository;

    @Override
    public void save(User user) {
        repository.save(user);
    }

    @Override
    public List<User> findAll() {
        List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();
        if (repository.findAll() != null) {
            Iterator<User> it = repository.findAll().iterator();
            while (it.hasNext())
                users.add(it.next());
        }
        return users;
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(User user) {
        repository.delete(user);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean checkExists(Long id) {
        return repository.findOne(id) != null;
    }

}
```

**main.java.persistence.repositories.UserRepository**

```
@Transactional
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

    public User findByEmail(String email);

}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It says, it failed to inject the depedency  private UserService uS; . Can you check in  your Application.class, if you have @ComponentScan  annotation is provided? If it is provided, check base package. If it is not try to provide it.

Comment: @LyjuIEdwinson yeah thanks, that solved my problem... but now I'm getting another one so I'll add another question.

Comment: good nice to know that it fixed the problem. if you are starting a new Spring project I suggest you to download an existing project and start from there. it will make your life very easier. You can do it simply using CLIs or STS tool or from web  https://spring.io/projects