# @ComponentScan JSON information replaces the HTML views

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-annotations

Maybe the title is not the best to explain the problem, but I'll try to explain it as best as possible.

I have an Spring Boot Application using JPA and MySQL, so in order to check everything worked properly, I made a simple CRUD test for my database, and I found problems with autowiring which are explained in [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43170406/why-am-i-obtaining-a-nested-exception-when-using-autowired-annotation-in-spring). The solution for those problems was just adding the `@ComponentScan` annotation to my `Application.java`.

It was the solution for the test because it run without problems, but then I find another problem. Apart from the test, I need my application to show a list of Proposals made by some Users and also some Comments. Before adding that annotation, the HTMLs showed the [correct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3G3gi.jpg) information, but after adding it shows [information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bm1An.jpg) about the database in JSON format on the main page and if I try to navigate to "localhost:8080/viewProposal" p.e. it shows a WhiteLabel error page with error code 404. I have no idea why it is replacing the HTMLs because I have just one controller and is not a RESTController. These are my classes:

**Application.java**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EntityScan("persistence.model")
@EnableJpaRepositories("persistence.repositories")
@ComponentScan("services.impl")
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

**MainController.java**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class MainController {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MainController.class);
    private List<SseEmitter> sseEmitters = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>());


    private Map<String, Proposal> proposals = generateProposals();

    @RequestMapping({"/live","/"})
    public String landing(Model model) {
        return "index";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/viewProposal")
    public String viewProposal(Model model, Long id) {
        //put the object in the map
        return "viewProposal";
    }

    @KafkaListener(topics = "newVote")
    public void listen(String data) {
        String[] contents = data.split(";");

        if(contents.length!=2)
            return;

        Proposal p;
        int newVote;

        if (proposals.containsKey(contents[0]))
            p = proposals.get(contents[0]);
        else {
            p = new Proposal();
            p.setTitle(contents[0]);
            proposals.put(p.getTitle(), p);
        }

        if (contents[1].equals("+"))
            newVote = +1;
        else if (contents[1].equals("-"))
            newVote = -1;
        else
            newVote = 0;

        p.setNumberOfVotes(p.getNumberOfVotes() + newVote);

        logger.info("New message received: \"" + data + "\"");
    }

    private static Map<String, Proposal> generateProposals() {
        Map<String, Proposal> lista = new HashMap<String, Proposal>();

        Proposal p = new Proposal();
        p.setTitle("tituloPrueba");

        lista.put("tituloPrueba", p);

        return lista;
    }

    @ModelAttribute("proposals")
    public Map<String, Proposal> getProposals() {
        return proposals;
    }

    public void setProposals(Map<String, Proposal> proposals) {
        this.proposals = proposals;
    }

}
```

**MvcConfiguration**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class MvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{
    @Bean
    public ViewResolver getViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/resources/templates/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".html");
        return resolver;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(
        DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }    

    @Override
    public void configureContentNegotiation(ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.defaultContentType(MediaType.TEXT_HTML);
    }    
}
```

If you want to see the rest of the classes, please go to [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43170406/why-am-i-obtaining-a-nested-exception-when-using-autowired-annotation-in-spring) everything is in there.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: may you show your viewresolver configuration?

Comment: @AngeloImmediata I've just added it, sorry for the delay.